# Figuresize when using Seaborn FacetGrid

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to draw(visualize titanic dataset) using seaborn and pyplot . When I try and use the FacetGrid feature from Pycharm the figure draw overlaps 
[image]

Whereas if I draw this on Jupyter notebook the size of the figure is too small. Any ideas on how to fix both ?

[image]

here is the code that I am using

```
from  matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df_train = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
#plt.figure(figsize=(16, 6))
_=sns.FacetGrid(df_train,col='Cabin')
_.map(plt.hist,"Fare")
plt.show()
```

Comment: could you please share the code you used to generate this?

Comment: added sample code to the Q